# How to exclude contacts who already received a mailing?

Tags: civievent, civimail

As part of my online events, all participants should receive various mailings throughout the event.
The problem is that I have people who keep registering to the event, and then they should receive the emails that the others had already received so far.
How can I re-send a mailing to all participants of an event, excluding all the participants who had already received that mailing in the past?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When composing your mailing use the "Recipients" field to exclude recipients of one or more past mailings. Here's a screenshot of this in action:

[image]

Specifically, you would choose one group to *include* (which can be a [smart group](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/smart-groups/) based on the event), and several *mailings* to exclude.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this. The main problem is that it's just too easy, and the first time you want to do it, you don't expect it to be so easy.